# webpage in the landscape mode of iPhone

Tags: iphone, landscape, horizontal-scrolling

I want to lock the horizontal scroll of my webpage in mobile Safari.
Specifying the width n height in `background.js` fixed the problem for iPad :

```
if(B.msie<=8 || B.iPad) (function() {
    var mixin, i,   
    bg_tile = static_url('bg_tile');
    if(B.iPhone || B.iPad) {
    bg_tile = static_url('iOS_bg_tile');
    }

    for(i in mixin={
    width: 768,
    height: 600,
    fade: false,
    srcs: {
        tile: bg_tile,
        radial: static_url('bg_radial')
    },
    customCSS: function(el) {
        el.style.background = 'url('+this.srcs.tile+')';
    },
    mainSrc: 'radial'
    }) if(mixin.hasOwnProperty(i)) BG.BackgroundView.prototype[i] = mixin[i];
})();
```

But if I add a similar block for iPhone it's giving zooming problem.

Any suggestion how can I lock the horizontal scroll in iPhone?

Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a meta tag for viewport, fix the width as device width.

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = 320">
```